# PDF report generation in R markdown, loading icon is present

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I open the generated `R markdown` report in `Safari` and try to save it as `pdf`, the generated `.pdf` file has loading icon on top of the document:

[image]

Even though no loading is going on, it is actually issue with the `.pdf` file generation. How could I remove it?

> Update

```
> devtools::session_info()
Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.1.447)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2018-05-03
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to generate the pdf directly from R markdown? I mean that's one of the strenghts of Markdown, you write your doc, and then can generate html, latex, pdf, docx, etc. from it...

Comment: I can not do that, there is no button `knitr` at the top, only `Run Document`

Comment: do you have `output: pdf_document` in your markdown document's YAML front matter ?

Comment: No, it is `output: html_document`, but if I change it to `output: pdf_document`, there is an error upon generating `.pdf`: `unused arguments`

Comment: I think it's worth the trouble to try and solve these errors. Maybe do a new post about this or edit this one to tackle this issue. Please include a sample doc include the yaml part, and the full error you get.

Comment: Can you post the output of `devtools::session_info()`?